# Displaying UIView1 above UIView2, but having UIView2 above UIView1 input-wise

Tags: ios, ios5, uiview, core-graphics, calayer

This is an odd scenario, but I have two overlapping UIViews, and I need to display one above the other, but give the lower one precedence on receiving input. If that makes any sense. I can clarify if needed.

Preferably I would like to do this in Interface Builder, but assuming that is not possible, is there a way to do it programmatically?

Edit: Got it working, thanks to @jaydee3. Just override the `hitTest:` method of UIView1 as follows. UIView2 is `self.otherView`.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.otherView && [self.otherView pointInside:[self.otherView convertPoint:point fromView:self] withEvent:event])
    {
        return [self.otherView hitTest:[self.otherView convertPoint:point fromView:self] withEvent:event];
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't need input on view1, just set `view1.userInteractionEnabled = NO`. This can be done in IB.

Otherwise, you have to use some code. Eg. subclass UIView for the view1 and override the `hitTest: …` method. If the touched point is overlapping with the other view, return `[view2 hitTest: …]`.

Comment: I still need to receive input on UIView1, so I will have to do something like the latter method. Hopefully that will work. Thanks.